# Outputting rows into another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sets of data stored in two different sheets. I need to run an analysis which prints out the **non-duplicate** rows (i.e. row is present in one and not the other) found in the sheets and print them in a new sheet.

I can do the comparison fine - it is relatively simple with ranges and the `For Next` method. I currently store the non-duplicates in two different collections, each representing the non-duplicates in each sheet. However I am having trouble deciding how to proceed with pasting the duplicate rows on the new sheet.

I thought about storing the entire row into a collection but printing the row out of the collection in the new sheet seems non-trivial: I would have to determine the size of the collection, set the appropriate range and then iterate through the collection and print them out. I would also like to truncate this data which would add another layer of complexity.

The other method I thought was simply storing the row number and using `Range.Select.Copy` and `PasteSpecial`. The advantage of this is that I can truncate however much I wish, however this seems incredibly hacky to me (essentially using VBA to simulate user input) and I am not sure on performance hits.

What are the relative merits or is there a better way?

Comment: So you have 2 collections of ranges?

Comment: At the moment, yes. Each collection storing the rows I want to print in the new sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been tackling a similar problem at work this week. I have come up with two methods:

First you could simply iterate through each collection one row at a time, and copy the values to the new sheet:

```
Function PasteRows1(ByRef srcRows As Collection, ByRef dst As Worksheet)
    Dim row As Range
    Dim curRow As Integer

    curRow = 1
    For Each row In srcRows
        dst.rows(curRow).Value = row.Value
        curRow = curRow + 1
    Next
End Function
```

This has the benefit of not using the `Range.Copy` method and so the user's clipboard is preserved. If you are not copying an entire row then you will have to create a range that starts at the first cell of the row and then resize it using `Range.Resize`. So the code inside the `for` loop would roughly be:

```
Dim firstCellInRow as Range
Set firstCellInRow = dst.Cells(curRow,1)
firstCellInRow.Resize(1,Row.columns.Count).Value = row.Value 
curRow = curRow + 1
```

The second method I thought of uses the `Range.Copy`. Like so:

```
Function PasteRows2(ByRef srcRows As Collection, ByRef dst As Worksheet)
    Dim row As Range
    Dim disjointRange As Range

    For Each row In srcRows
        If disjointRange is Nothing Then
            Set disjointRange = row
        Else
            Set disjointRange = Union(disjointRange, row)
        End If
    Next
    disjointRange.Copy
    dst.Paste
End Function
```

While this does use the `.Copy` method it also will allow you to copy all of the rows in one shot which is nice because you will avoid partial copies if excel ever crashes in the middle of your macro.

Let me know if either of these methods satisfy your needs :)

Comment: Will `row.value = srcRow.value` copy the srcRow into the new row? I didn't know this! Thanks for your answer but you've mainly addressed the first solution...I ideally want to truncate it to the first 5 columns of the row as well which is why I think I might end up using `.Copy` but I'm really unsure on how much it affects performance. Have an upvote anyway :)

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand, but can't you simply truncate the first 5 columns when you are first picking up the rows into the collection?

Comment: So is your question whether or not to use `Copy`? Or is it "does `Copy` have a negative influence on performance"? Please clarify.

Comment: I honestly don't remember but have an accepted anyway